# Mysql json datatypes

Tags: mysql, json

Am trying to extract some json numbers from a json column in mysql database and save them to another column of type double

my sql statement is

```
update city
set Population = Info
where (
    select CAST(JSON_UNQUOTE(JSON_EXTRACT(Info, '$.Population'))as DECIMAL)
);
```

but i keep getting this error:

> ERROR: 3156: Invalid JSON value for CAST to DOUBLE from column Info at row 1

the Info column is type json and the Population is type Double

[image: Screenshot]

Answer (score 0):

You can't make `set Population = Info`, they have entirely different column types.

Are you by chance just trying to do a simple update?

```
update city
set Population = JSON_EXTRACT(Info, '$.Population')
```

Comment: Glad it helped. I honestly couldn't figure out the intended purpose of the `where` clause.

Comment: Hello how would use a python script to perfom this update to mysql database then display the results